# Leaflet: Change the layer source after some zoom

Tags: leaflet

I've made a TMS WMS-cached layer using gdal2tiles.py and EPSG:3857 at 10 to 17 zoom levels. But I'd like to change the layer source after 17 level. Example: change to the original WMS source that will render the 18 and 19 levels.

Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a `zoom`or `zoomend` event combined with `getZoom()` method to change the current tile layer. I recommend you to read the [API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-event) on the topic.

You can find an [example here](http://bl.ocks.org/cccruzr/d4ccd2c258753699b1eeb03f5141539b).